# Giridview cell double click event is not fired?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I am developing winform application using C# and Gridview cell double click event is not fired . I have given below my source code

```
private void gridView2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridView view = (GridView)sender;
            DataTable getGrid = (DataTable)Popup_Grid.DataSource;
            int RowVal = gridView2.FocusedRowHandle;
            string FieldVal = ERPModule.isnull(Convert.ToString(gridView2.GetRowCellValue(RowVal, gridView2.Columns["DisplayName"])), "");

            if (RowVal != -1)
            {
                string SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
                string SelectionEnd = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(richTextBox1.SelectionStart, richTextBox1.Text.Length - richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
                richTextBox1.Text = SelectionStart + FieldVal + SelectionEnd;
                Displaydata_Popup_Container.Parent.FindForm().Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Displaydata_Popup_Container.Parent.FindForm().Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.ErrorLog.WriteToFile(DataFile.errorFile, "PrintList : gridView2_DoubleClick()", ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What you want to simplify

Comment: any possibilities is there passing type messages? Object variable and fields Only changing. so please let me know any possibilities for simplify this code

Answer (score 2):

Extract common logic to the function (possible to extension method)

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static int CountChequeStatusOf(this DataTable table, string condition)
    {
        var count = table.Compute("Count(ChequeStatus)", $"ChequeStatus = '{condition}'");
        return count == DbNull.Value ? 0 : (int)count;
    }
}
```

Then "reuse" it

```
var table = (DataTable)grid_cheque.DataSource;

this.lblNew.Text = table.CountChequeStatusOf("New").ToString();
this.lbl_Issued.Text = table.CountChequeStatusOf("Issued").ToString();
this.lblCancel.Text = table.CountChequeStatusOf("Cancelled").ToString();
this.lbldishonour.Text = table.CountChequeStatusOf("DisHonour").ToString();
```

Comment: I have used your code and am getting error like "Extension method must be defined in a top level static class; DataTableExtensions is a nested class"

Comment: @Raj -pretty clear error message ;). Put `DataTableExtensions` class outside of your current class or to the separate file.

Comment: Yes I did but showing error DBNull is not exist in the current content. Please can you give me briefly?

Comment: Use `System.DbNull` or add `using System;` in the top of the file